# Inverse Document Frequency of a corpus

Tags: python

I have a folder with 10 txt files. I am trying to compute IDF of a given term. But my output is differing from expected. Here is my code for idf.

Here s is a set which contains union of all words from those 10 files.

```
def idf(term):
    i = 0
    doc_counts = 0
    totaldocs = 10
    if term in s:
        for filename in os.listdir(root_of_my_corpus):
            file = open(os.path.join(root_of_my_corpus, filename), "r", encoding='UTF-8')
            idfdoc = file.read()
            file.close() 
            idfdoc = idfdoc.lower()
            tokenidf = tokenizer.tokenize(idfdoc)
            if term in tokenidf:
                doc_counts+=1
    return(math.log(totaldocs/doc_counts))
```

Comment: Can you provide the output, along with the expected output, and maybe some sample data?

Comment: suppose a term= 'xyz' is repeated in 7 docs, the exact idf value is not getting returned by my code.

Comment: That's still not enough information.  For example, what is `s` in your program?  Why is `totaldocs = 10`, and not the number of files in `root_of_my_corpus`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just write a small demo of how to calculate idf. The toy data I used are four txt files as below

- 1.txt content: "Hello world 1"
- 2.txt content: "Hello world 2"
- 3.txt content: "Hello world 3"
- 4.txt content: "Hello world 4"

The code is basically load all txt content into a dictionary and then calculate idf for each word.  Here is the code:

```
import os
import math
from collections import defaultdict


def idf_calc(path):
    # load data
    file_paths = [(path + item, str(item.split(".")[0])) for item in os.listdir(path)]
    contents = {}
    for item in file_paths:
        file_path, file_name = item
        raw = ""
        with open(file_path, "r") as fp:
            data = fp.readlines()
            if len(data) > 0:
                raw = data[0].strip()
        contents[file_name] = raw


    # idf calculate
    result = {}
    total_cnt = len(contents)
    words = list(set([word for item in contents for word in contents[item].split()]))

    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        cnt = sum([1 for item in contents if word in contents[item]])
        idf = math.log(total_cnt / cnt)
        result[word] = "%.3f" % (idf)

    print result


idf_calc("../data/txt/")
```

Results

```
{'1': '1.386', '3': '1.386', '2': '1.386', '4': '1.386', 'world': '0.000', 'Hello': '0.000'}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Other part of project is to get count of words, but count differs if i use large corpus.
Code:

listwords = []
for filename in os.listdir(corpus_root):
    file = open(os.path.join(corpus_root, filename), "r", encoding='UTF-8')
    listdoc = file.read()
    file.close() 
    listdoc = listdoc.lower()
    tokensget = tokenizer.tokenize(listdoc)
    for w in tokensget:
        if w not in stop_words:
            listwords.append(w)
#print(sorted(listwords))
def getcount(chkword):
    countw = 0
    for w in listwords:
        if w==chkword:
            countw = countw + 1    
    return countw

Comment: Other part of project is to get count of words, but count differs if i use large corpus. Code: 
listwords = [] 
for filename in os.listdir(corpus_root):
 file = open(os.path.join(corpus_root, filename), "r", encoding='UTF-8') listdoc = file.read() 
file.close() 
listdoc = listdoc.lower() 
tokensget = tokenizer.tokenize(listdoc) 
     for w in tokensget:
       if w not in stop_words:
           listwords.append(w) 
def getcount(chkword): 
      countw = 0
      for w in listwords: 
            if w==chkword: 
                  countw = countw + 1 
      return countw

Comment: also the code which u have given for IDF is difficult for me to understand. I am beginner in python.

Comment: I need to create a function which returns IDF of a term:

for ex: getidf(term):

is a function which returns idf of 'term' with those of my corpus

Comment: How can I load all 10 txt files in separate list? so that I can calculate term frequency and IDF.

Comment: @Sameer you can read the "# load data" part of my code, which is actually loading several txt files

Comment: I tried to implement a code on my own which calculates TF values and IDF values in separate dictionary. Now I am stuck in other part which calculates TF x IDF between those files.

For each of 10 files, I have stored TF values in 10 dictionary and IDF values in 1 dictionary. Now I want to multiply TF value of Dict 1 with IDF and store TFxIDF in another Dictionary. I am stuck here. Help me pls